# Pass Table name dynamically in SSIS lookup transformation

Tags: ssis, lookup

How to pass table name dynamically in Lookup transformation.
I have tried using Lookup.Sqlcommand in data flow task but it did not work.

Requirement is to do incremental upload to target database table , for eg 10 new records from the source needs to be pushed to target tables(3 tables with same table structure),
Table Names are Manager_Tbl , Supervisor_Tbl, Labor_tbl , Table Colums are "Job title, Employee Number(PrimaryKey) ,Employee Name , Worker Location " .

The column called Job Title (values-Manager,Supervisor,Labor) determines which table I need to push the data into the target,
based on the Job title I need to check in corresponding target table if the Employee Number already exist in the target table, if exisits then using checksum transformation i determine whether it is an update or new insert in to the target. 
So how can I change the table name dynamically in the lookup transformation based on the Job title column

Comment: You can't What happens to your lookup mappings when you have a table with completely different columns?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Sounds like an XY Problem. Sorry I don't have link to definition.

Comment: hi raghav,I have mentioned below a solution for your problem, please check and let me know if still you have any problem..

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a variable ‘**TableName**’ with data type **object** and then drag a `EXECUTE SQL TASK`in the control flow and then put the `SQL` query in **SQL Statement** .
`SQL Query` is given below , and then please follow the snapshot step by step for your problem.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM YOURDATABASE_NAME.SYS.TABLES;
```

[image]
[image]

After this call the variable **TableName** in your loop , I hope you got the solution for your problem.

Comment: That's an execute SQL Task, not a lookup transformation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid,Yes I know that this is not lookup transformation ,you can use variable value